# I want to open an html file in a new tab on button click in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack-html-loader

I want to open an html file which is in my local, in a new tab on button click in react component. I am trying to import the html file and then use window.open() method of javascript for this purpose. But for importing the html file I need html-loader plugin. But I get this when I try to install the plugin using npm - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rlqu.png)

Is there any other way to open an html file in a new tab on button click in react js and if not, why is the html-loader plugin not getting installed?

Comment: Why can’t you use a regular link with a `target` attribute to open it in a new window? Is there a reason you need to import the html file (as opposed to treating it like a static asset)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be d one with Vanilla JavaScript, I don't believe you should need the `html-loader` plugin:

```js
button onClick="Open()">Link</button>
 
<script>
    function Open() {
        window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
    }
</script>
```

`html-loader` is used to read HTML files in as strings (see the [npm package page here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader)). As for why your installation isn't working, it appears that you are having issues with some other packages you have installed (ant-design icons, material UI, and react). Perhaps try removing all conflicting packages with `npm uninstall [package-name]` and then subsequently reinstalling the ones you need.

Comment: I did this too, but what is happening is a new tab opens having the file path of the html file but instead of opening the html file it opens the same window

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-router-dom, you might find the following code helpful.

```
<Link target={"_blank"} to="your-link">Your Link</Link>
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but what is happening is a new tab opens having the file path of the html file but instead of opening the html file it opens the same window

Comment: Your server may be configured to always serve index.html for any path outside of your static assets directory (public or whatever).

Comment: Ohhh, how can I change this setting then?

Comment: It would vary depending on your host/server. The easiest solution would be to put the html file in your public directory and link to it there.

Comment: 2nd @ray. Can you share more about your tech stack, Tanvi Narkhede ? Cheers!

Comment: hey, its React js, redux for frontend and python and sql for backend

Comment: what do you use for navigation in the frontend?

Comment: navigation? I didnt understand